# Librem machine stuck "Booting from Hard Disk" after installing NixOS

Tags: boot, nixos

Just tried installing both NixOS 21.05 and 22.05 (wiping the whole disk before each install) on a Librem Mini LMv2-01, but when booting it just gets stuck at the "Booting from Hard Disk..." step with a furiously blinking cursor. Is there anything I can do to get a clear idea what's happening, or is this a known issue?

Comment: Booting the ISO worked? Did you install a UEFI or legacy bootloader?

Comment: I installed UEFI, which failed. I then tried with legacy, which worked. Is UEFI just not supported?

Comment: That depends on your laptop's firmware. I'd be very surprised if it doesn't support EFI though. Which way did the ISO boot? You can test this by trying to look at the EFI vars from the live env. If they don't exist, you're in legacy boot.